# proprietary authentication to LDAP

Tags: ldap

I have a proprietary external authentication platform, that I can use to authenticate with over REST-WS.
Now I would like to have / build a way to have numerous other web services (website, forum, ...) that can use this authentication platform.
However, I don't want to create an authentication module for each service because they all are build on different languages (Ruby, PHP, ...).
Instead, most of those services, support LDAP authentication out of the box...

So, I would like to know if it's possible somehow to create an LDAP server, that fetches all the data (through REST-WS) from the third-party authentication platform

Note: it should be a linux solution...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward way at this time is for someone (you) to write either a `SASL` plugin or `pam` module to be used by OpenLDAP's [Pass-Through authentication](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/guide.html#Pass-Through%20authentication).

Straight forward isn't necessarily the same as easy.

Comment: Perfect, this is what I need... I will indeed have to write this plugin myself; I will try. Thanks!